# Two different projects in one web-solution

Tags: asp.net-core, abp

I am new to `Asp.net core` and `Abp.io`.
I have two completely independent projects *(Models, Services, Controllers etc)* except the AppUser and permissions.

But then the two projects should be merged on one Intranet-Side:

Project 1:
http://intranet/project1

Project 2:
http://intranet/project2

Is there first a new ApplicationApp created and then modules to it?

Answer (score 0):

There are many layers to this question and multiple answers that start with "depending on" but let's assume you are using the dotnet cli.

1. Create a folder that will hold both projects - mkdir web-solution
2. `dotnet new sln -o web-solution.` This will create web-solution.sln
3. `dotnet new mvc -o project1` . This will create a project1/project1.csproj
4. `dotnet sln add project1` - This will add project1/project1.csproj to the solution
5. `dotnet new mvc -o project2` - this will create a project2/project2.csproj
6. `dotnet sln add project2` - this will add project2/project2.csproj to the solution

Everything follows this pattern. If you want to create a class library classlib to be used by both projects then

1. `dotnet new classlib -o classlib`
2. `dotnet sln add classlib`
3. `cd project1`
4. `dotnet add reference ../classlib`

Everything follows this pattern. If you are using Visual Studio then the pattern is to create a solution from the file menu. You can then do the other stuff by right-clicking on the solution to "add project".  Again... it depends.

Comment: Hello,

thank you very much for the quick answers.
It would be important for me to be able to implement it in https://abp.io/

Comment: See... it does depend. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, what you need is a [class library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/class-library-overview). With `class library` You can make totally separate from each other projects in one solution and even include them into other solutions.

You can read more and find a simple example of adding `class library` projects into your solution using `Visual Studio` [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/building-a-net-core-class-library/).